# How to extract all h2 texts from some URLs and store to CSV?

Tags: python, html, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Need to extract all `h2` text from some links and I tried it by using `BeautifulSoup`, but it didn't worked.

I also want to output them to CSV

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

r01 = requests.get("https://www.seikatsu110.jp/library/vermin/vr_termite/23274/") 
r02 = requests.get("https://yuko-navi.com/termite-control-subsidies")


soup_content01 = BeautifulSoup(r01.content, "html.parser")
soup_content02 = BeautifulSoup(r02.content, "html.parser")

alltxt01 = soup_content01.get_text()
alltxt02 = soup_content02.get_text()

with open('h2.csv', 'w+',newline='',encoding='utf-8') as f:
    n = 0

    for subheading01 in soup_content01.find_all('h2'):
        sh01 = subheading01.get_text()

        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([n, sh01])
        n += 1

    for subheading02 in soup_content02.find_all('h2'):
        sh02 = subheading02.get_text()

        writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writerow([n, sh01, sh02])
        n += 1
pass
```

expected csv output is as below:

| sh01 | sh02 |
| --- | --- |
| シロアリ駆除に適用される補助金や保険は？ | 1章 シロアリ駆除工事に補助金はない！ |
| シロアリ駆除の費用を補助金なしで抑える方法 | 2章 確定申告時に「雑損控除」申請がおすすめ |
| シロアリ駆除の費用ってどれくらいかかる？ | 3章 「雑損控除」として負担してもらえる金額 |
| 要件を満たせば加入できるシロアリ専門の保険がある？ | 4章 「雑損控除」の申請方法 |
| シロアリには5年保証がある！ | 5章 損したくないなら信頼できる業者を選ぼう！ |
| まとめ | まとめ |
| この記事の監修者 ナカザワ氏について |  |
| この記事の監修者 ナカザワ氏について |  |
| シロアリ駆除のおすすめ記事 |  |
| 関連記事カテゴリ一覧 |  |
| シロアリ駆除の記事アクセスランキング |  |
| シロアリ駆除の最新記事 |  |
| カテゴリ別記事⼀覧 |  |
| シロアリ駆除の業者を地域から探す |  |
| 関連カテゴリから業者を探す |  |
| シロアリ駆除業者ブログ |  |
| サービスカテゴリ |  |
| 生活110番とは |  |
| 加盟希望・ログイン |  |

Please somebody tell me what's wrong with this code.

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] and share some code you have tried. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in addation to approach of @Barry the Platipus with `itertools`, that is great. - `pandas` is also my favorite and there is an alternative way with native [`dict comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Iterate your urls and create a `dict` that holds number or url as `key` and a `list` of heading texts as value. These could be easily transformed to a `DataFrame` and exported to CSV:

```
d = {}
for e,url in enumerate(urls,1):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
    d[f'sh{e}'] = [h.get_text() for h in soup.find_all('h2')]

pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.items()]))#.to_csv('yourfile.csv', index = False)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

urls = ['https://www.seikatsu110.jp/library/vermin/vr_termite/23274/','https://yuko-navi.com/termite-control-subsidies']
d = {}
for e,url in enumerate(urls,1):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
    d[f'sh{e}'] = [h.get_text() for h in soup.find_all('h2')]

pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in d.items()]))#.to_csv('yourfile.csv', index = False)
```

##### Output

| sh1 | sh2 |
| --- | --- |
| シロアリ駆除に適用される補助金や保険は？ | 1章 シロアリ駆除工事に補助金はない！ |
| シロアリ駆除の費用を補助金なしで抑える方法 | 2章 確定申告時に「雑損控除」申請がおすすめ |
| シロアリ駆除の費用ってどれくらいかかる？ | 3章 「雑損控除」として負担してもらえる金額 |
| 要件を満たせば加入できるシロアリ専門の保険がある？ | 4章 「雑損控除」の申請方法 |
| シロアリには5年保証がある！ | 5章 損したくないなら信頼できる業者を選ぼう！ |
| まとめ | まとめ |
| この記事の監修者 ナカザワ氏について | nan |
| この記事の監修者 ナカザワ氏について | nan |
| シロアリ駆除のおすすめ記事 | nan |
| 関連記事カテゴリ一覧 | nan |
| シロアリ駆除の記事アクセスランキング | nan |
| シロアリ駆除の最新記事 | nan |
| カテゴリ別記事⼀覧 | nan |
| シロアリ駆除の業者を地域から探す | nan |
| 関連カテゴリから業者を探す | nan |
| シロアリ駆除業者ブログ | nan |
| サービスカテゴリ | nan |
| 生活110番とは | nan |
| 加盟希望・ログイン | nan |

Comment: I just completed a similar solution, but you beat me to it :)  `for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    h2s = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser").find_all('h2')
    df[f'sh{i}'] = pd.Series([h2.get_text(strip=True) for h2 in h2s])`

Comment: @SergeyK Hey, same wavelength with `pd.Series()` ;) - Creating them directly in `for-loop` I had not thought of at all, great.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to reach your goal as stated:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from itertools import zip_longest

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

r01 = requests.get("https://www.seikatsu110.jp/library/vermin/vr_termite/23274/", headers=headers) 
r02 = requests.get("https://yuko-navi.com/termite-control-subsidies", headers=headers)

first_url_headings = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in bs(r01.text, 'html.parser').select('h2')]
second_url_headings = [x.get_text(strip=True) for x in bs(r02.text, 'html.parser').select('h2')]

df_list = list(zip_longest(first_url_headings, second_url_headings))
df = pd.DataFrame(df_list, columns = ['First site', 'Second site'])
df.to_csv('termites_stuffs.csv')
print(df)
```

Result in terminal (also saved as a csv file):

|  | First site | Second site |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | シロアリ駆除に適用される補助金や保険は？ | 1章 シロアリ駆除工事に補助金はない！ |
| 1 | シロアリ駆除の費用を補助金なしで抑える方法 | 2章 確定申告時に「雑損控除」申請がおすすめ |
| 2 | シロアリ駆除の費用ってどれくらいかかる？ | 3章 「雑損控除」として負担してもらえる金額 |
| 3 | 要件を満たせば加入できるシロアリ専門の保険がある？ | 4章 「雑損控除」の申請方法 |
| 4 | シロアリには5年保証がある！ | 5章 損したくないなら信頼できる業者を選ぼう！ |
| 5 | まとめ | まとめ |
| 6 | この記事の監修者 ナカザワ氏について |  |
| 7 | この記事の監修者 ナカザワ氏について |  |
| 8 | シロアリ駆除のおすすめ記事 |  |
| 9 | 関連記事カテゴリ一覧 |  |
| 10 | シロアリ駆除の記事アクセスランキング |  |
| 11 | シロアリ駆除の最新記事 |  |
| 12 | カテゴリ別記事⼀覧 |  |
| 13 | シロアリ駆除の業者を地域から探す |  |
| 14 | 関連カテゴリから業者を探す |  |
| 15 | シロアリ駆除業者ブログ |  |
| 16 | サービスカテゴリ |  |
| 17 | 生活110番とは |  |
| 18 | 加盟希望・ログイン |  |

Documentation for BeautifulSoup: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Also for Requests: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And for pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html